# How can assign a data-group value to an html element created in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have a scenario where I need to conditionally slide up (or hide) sets of controls/elements. I like the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899263/how-can-i-invisiblize-groups-of-controls-via-jquery/30899358#30899358) from QBM5 about assigning data-groups to the controls that may be slid up (pardon my grammar) like so:

```
<input data-group="1" type="text" />
```

...but again, I am creating these controls via C#, not pure/straight HTML, so I need to add that data-group property to it somehow programmatically. But this attempt to do so with a TextBox (input, type=text):

```
boxRequesterName = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input"
};
boxRequesterName.DataGroup = 1; // Nice try, but there is no such property as "DataGroup"
cellTxtbx_1.Controls.Add(boxRequesterName);
dynamicTable.Rows.Add(row1);
```

...won't work, because there is no "DataGroup" property on the TextBox.

What can I do to add the equivalent of data-group="1" to my control?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1318795/1600844

Comment: @GustavoSuarez that answer pertains to ASP.NET MVC; this looks like ASP.NET WebForms though so it doesn't really apply.

Comment: It's Sharepoint, so it is ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, please notice that `DataGroup` or `data-group` is nothing predefined, it's an [HTML5 data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) which can be named anything you like.

Since you are working with ASP.NET and WebForms, you can use the `Attributes` collection on your `TextBox` element like this:

```
boxRequesterName.Attributes.Add("data-group", "1");
```

See on MSDN [WebControl.Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [AttributeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Cool; this should work, except if the users don't have an "HTML5-powered" browser.